# Should I need to match input image size and images of my datasets?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolov5, yolov4

I try to create datasets for yolov5.

But, I have wondered how to decide images size in my datasets.

Should i decide input image size is the correspondence of images of my datasets?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to this offcial [URL](https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/darknet_faq/#time_to_train)
,The image size of the data set did not seem to matter.

Comment: Can you post some relevant content from that link? Links tend to break over time, making answers without details less useful in the long term.